# SSH-AGENT could not open connection

Tags: windows, bash, ssh, git

I try to link my SSH key with SSH Agent.

I'm on Windows 7 Pro, and I'm using Git Bash console.

I've this folder structure:

`C:\Users\MyName.ssh\id_rsa`

Where I've put my SSH key files as follow:

- myname.ssh (about private SSH key)
- myname.pub (about public SSH key)

After this, I launch my SSH Agent like this:

By Git Bash Console:
`ssh-agent -s`

The echo is the follow:

```
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/ssh-LpOZfV5krHuP/agent.3984; export SSH_AUTH_SOCK;
SSH:AGENT_PID=6128; export SSH_AGENT_PID;
echo Agent pid 6128;
```

Now, if I run my Task Summary I show the ssh_agent.exe as pid 6128 correctly.

Now I try to link my agent with my SSH key as follow:

- The first attempt:
  `ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa` **FAILED**
- The second attempt:
  `ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa/myname.ssh` **FAILED**
- The third attempt:
  `ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa/myname.pub` **FAILED**
- Other attempts:
  I tried with complete path but always... **FAILED**

Please if you know my fault, help me.

The error returned:

`could not open a connection to your authentication agent`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are behind a firewall please try this before:

```
git config --global url."https://".insteadOf git://
```

Comment: what should be the url to be?

Answer (score 2):

You need to *execute* the output of ssh-agent to apply the changes to your current shell:

```
eval $(ssh-agent -s)
```

Comment: Dear, your solution resolve my issue but now I have another error. After this, I launch: git submodule update, but console returns unable to connect to github.com errno = No error